# Azure Function Binding Expression to access a dictionary value

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to create the bindings in a function.json file that will enable the input of a Cosmos DB document depending on the Service Bus message that triggers the Function.

I want to use a value in the UserProperties dictionary of the Service Bus message. The documentation tells me that this is available for use within the bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata

However I don't seem to be able to use a value within the dictionary as I get the following error:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Invalid template '{UserProperties['MyId']}'. Invalid template expression 'UserProperties['MyId'].`

The contents of my function.json are:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "mytopic",
      "subscriptionName": "mysubscription",
      "connection": "myservicebus_SERVICEBUS"
    },
    {
      "name": "documents",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "Cache",
      "collectionName": "ProductVersion",
      "id" : "{UserProperties['MyId']}",
      "partitionKey": "{UserProperties['MyId']}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "mycosmos_COSMOSDB",     
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions-and-patterns says that I can use dot notation to access the properties of objects, but there is no mention of accessing dictionary values.

I have also tried double quotes `"partitionKey": "{UserProperties[\"MyId\"]}"` and dot notation `"partitionKey": "{UserProperties.MyId}"` but these don't work either.

The Function happens to be written in Python, but hopefully that isn't relevant.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not supported?

**Update 1**
The error I get when using `{UserProperties.MyId}` is:

```
Exception: TypeError: unable to decode incoming TypedData: unsupported combination of TypedData field None and expected binding type serviceBusTrigger
Stack:   File "d:\Workspace\MyFunction\.env\lib\site-packages\azure\functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 250, in _handle__invocation_request
    pytype=pb_type_info.pytype)
  File "d:\Workspace\MyFunction\.env\lib\site-packages\azure\functions_worker\bindings\meta.py", line 291, in from_incoming_proto
    f'unable to decode incoming TypedData: '
```

So perhaps this is an issue specific to Python?

**Update2**
This error is occuring whether the property is a dictionary or not.
The `main` definition looks like this:

`def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage, documents: func.DocumentList):`

**Update 3**
The error occurs when the Service Bus message payload is empty. The issue has been reported: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/330

Comment: I'm not aware of python. In .NET form You should be able to bind your input parameter to this class and then access custom properties via `Message.UserProperties` dictionary.

Comment: `"{UserProperties.MyId}"` should work and my function did work with it. Could you provide the error(stack trace) you meet?

Comment: @JerryLiu I have just updated the OP with details of that error. The stacktrace looks liek it's in Python code (dispatcher.py) so perhaps it is specific to Python.

Comment: @JasonSteele My python function works so it may be related to your function code(`__init__.py`), could you elaborate? You could remove the cosmos input binding for now to test whether it results from service bus trigger itself.

Comment: @JerryLiu, if I remove the the cosmos input binding (and it's parameter from the `main` call in `__init__.py` ) it works fine, I get the message and am able to see the values in `UserProperties`. But thanks for letting me know, at least I know it should work,

Comment: I have tried using properties that aren't in `UserProperties` such as `MessageId` but I still get the same error so it's nothing to do with it being a dictionary. It looks like a general issue with the binding so I'll update the OP with the `main` definition.

Comment: @JasonSteele My function definition is identical to yours. What's your function runtime version? See `2.0.12285` right now and azure-function python package `1.0.0b3`.

Comment: @JerryLiu, this is a bit embarrassing: it turns out that the actual problem is messages without a payload. The payload wasn't necessary as the UserProperties had everything we needed. So although the trigger was working, the change to the messages broke it at the same time as adding the CosmosDB binding. I have raised an issue for it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/330

Comment: @JasonSteele Never mind, problem being solved is the best ending. You could post it(the update 3) as an answer for others to refer.